# Erro de javascript com WebBrowser

Tags: c#, adobe-flex

Estou criando uma aplicação com componente WebBrowser em C# mas ao executar o seguinte código ele me retorna erro de JavaScript e não executa minha outra aplicação que foi desenvolvida em Adobe Flex:

```
private void chamaPagina(string tipo)
{
    string url = "";
    string pac = "http://localhost/accelerated_pac_base.pac";

    if (tipo == "frete")
    {
        url = "http://localhost/frete.html#";
    }
    else
    {
        url = "http://localhost/posto.html#";
    }

    //Método externo para ler arquivo pac e configurar proxy
    WebRequest requestNavegador = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

    string dadosProxy = Proxy.GetProxyForUrlUsingPac(url, pac);

    if (dadosProxy != null)
    {
        requestNavegador.Proxy = new WebProxy(dadosProxy);
    }

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)requestNavegador.GetResponse();
    Stream receiveStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    webBrowser1.DocumentStream = receiveStream;
}
```

Porem se eu adicionar `webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;` ele não exibi as mensagens de erro e continua não executando minha aplicação em Adobe FLEX.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Executar o programa faz aparecer alguma mensagem de erro no console?

Comment: Não me retorna nenhum erro, aparece somente a mensagem de erro de script, se eu utilizar `webBrowser1.Navigate('http://localhost/frete.html#')` não ocorre o problema, mas eu preciso que seja aplicado proxy através do arquivo .pac

Comment: "Não me retorna nenhum erro, aparece somente a mensagem de erro de script" - qual é o texto exato da mensagem?

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/kUYfM.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O erro ocorre porque o motor do navegador que ele usa é o Ie e algumas Funções java script não rodam no Ie, o que aconteceu é que você só não deixou o erro aparecer mas ele esta ali, sugiro utilizar um try assim o erro acontece mas sua aplicação continua.